# Javascript Array join() returning blank string

Tags: javascript

Sorry, I am new to javascript and i'm just trying to get my feet wet.

I have used join()in the past without problems, but for some reason this join seems to return a blank string.

The information in myArray seems to be formatted correctly.

any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

```
  function titleCase(str) {
  var splitArray = str.split(" ");
  var myArray = [];
  var joinArray = myArray.join(' ');

  for (var i in splitArray) {
    myArray.push(splitArray[i].charAt(0).toUpperCase() + splitArray[i].slice(1).toLowerCase());
  }

  return joinArray;
}

titleCase("capitalize the first letter of each word in this string");
```

Comment: You're returning `joinArray`, which is created at a time `myArray` is empty. You can assign a joined array after the loop, or just return `myArray.join(' ')`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're defining joinArray before myArray has been filled. 
Try moving

```
var joinArray = myArray.join(' ');
```

to the line before

```
return joinArray;
```

Comment: Thanks. that makes a lot of sense now

Comment: No problem, happy to help.

Answer (score 2):

You were joining `myArray` before it had anything in it, and then returning it, unmodified.

```js
  function titleCase(str) {
    var splitArray = str.split(" ");
    var myArray = [];

    for (var i in splitArray) {
      myArray.push(splitArray[i].charAt(0).toUpperCase() + splitArray[i].slice(1).toLowerCase());
    }

    return myArray.join(' ');
  }

document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = titleCase("capitalize the first letter of each word in this string");
```

```html
<p id="result"></p>
```

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. Apparently position matters and the join was happening before the for loop had a chance to run.

Comment: Please mark one of the answers above as the answer (whichever you found more useful) instead of reiterating.